# Minimum of subtrees in maximal heap

Tags: python, recursion, heap

Given maximal heap as a tree, I have to found for each node a minimum in its subtree. F.e.

```
          5                                    1
          +                                    +
          |                                    |
          |                                    |
      4<--+-->3                            1<--+->3
      +       +           +--->            +      +
      |       |                            |      |
      |       +--+-->N                     |      +-->N
   2<-+-->1      |                    2<---+->1   |
   +      +      +-->N                +       +   +-->N
   |      |                           |       |
   |      |                         N<+>N   N<+>N
N<-+>N  N<+-->N
```

`2,1,3` are leafs which point to NULL. Expected result for this tree is apparently 1, but my algorithm returns 2 (First time drawing a tree in asciiArt) .Here is my algorithm:
   `

```
If node is None, return 0
If node has TWO children , return min(children1.key,children2.key)
If node has ONE children , return children.key
If node does NOT have children , return node.key
Go to left subtree
Go to right subtree
Return min
```

In python:

```
 def sub_rec(node):
    if node == None:
        return 0
    if node.right != None and node.left != None:
        return min(node.right.key,node.left.key)
    if node.right == None and node.left != None:
        return node.left.key
    if node.left == None and node.right != None:
        return node.right.key
    if node.left == None and node.right == None:
        return node.key
    x = sub_rec (node.left)
    y = sub_rec (node.right)
    return min(x,y)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the minimum for left and right nodes before it has a chance to recurse into them.
That should be the other way around.

I would rewrite it like this (not tested):

```
def list_min(list_):
    ''' returns the minimum value for the list ignoring None elements, or None if there are no values '''
    mn = None
    for li in list_ or []: 
        if li != None and (mn==None or li < mn):
            mn=li
    return mn

def sub_rec(node):
    if node == None:
        return None
    return list_min(sub_rec(node.left), sub_rec(node.right), node.key)
```